# GlusterFS unable to add a new peer

Tags: glusterfs

I am playing with / testing GlusterFS and I like it so far. I think I can put it to good use.

I setup 5 Virtual Machines on a server (this is just for the playing/testing part) and installed Ubuntu 12.04 Server on 4 out of 5 and Debian 64bit on the 5th.

1 is a client.
3x Ubuntu servers
1x Debian server.

I compiled gluster 3.3 from scratch on Debian as a test, I wanted to make notes and what not and to see how it went. The ubuntu boxes however are setup using apt.

The 3 ubuntu boxes are working fine. I have 3 Bricks in a stripe and it works great. The client can connect just fine and read/write data.

I am now trying to add the Debian peer to the first ubuntu server so that I can expand the stripe.

I can resolve the hostname, the FQDN and I can ping the ip address from all peers.
I can telnet to the Debian machine on 24007 just fine.
Yet when I try to probe it just sits there for a while and eventually just goes back to prompt and if I do a peer status I see:

Hostname: glusterfs-compiletest.domain.local
Uuid: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
State: Establishing Connection (Disconnected)

I have rebooted and restarted all the machines just in case.

No Firewalls at all. This is all on an internal server and I have made sure that there is no firewall (and again, I can telnet to the port)

Any ideas or anything I can try?

I am new to Gluster.

Thank you.

Luma

Answer (score 3):

Opening TCP port 24007 is not enough, as per http://gluster.org/community/documentation/index.php/Gluster_3.2:_Installing_GlusterFS_from_Source :

> Ensure that TCP ports 111, 24007,24008, 24009-(24009 + number of
>   bricks across all volumes) are open on all Gluster servers. If you
>   will be using NFS, open additional ports 38465 to 38467.

Ensure they are open and available on the *debian* host. Moreover, are you trying to "probe" the debian host *from* an ubuntu one? You should issue the command from inside the active cluster.